# Passing options to GraphicsRow

Tags: graphics, warning-messages, options

I'm trying to pass the options to a simple function based on `GraphicsRow` as in the example below, but I get a long list of errors.

```
showResults[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
      GraphicsRow[list,  FilterRules[{opts}, Options[GraphicsRow]]]

showResults[{1, 1}]
```

I cannot spot any error in the syntax of my function. Is it a bug?

I'm using MMA 11.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: The cause of the bug is that `GraphicsRow` can take a second argument, *spacing*, which can be a `List`.  So the empty list returned by `FilterRules` gets interpreted as spacings, and the internal code fails very poorly when it isn't the right shape.

Comment: you can also do: `showResults[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[GraphicsRow]] := 
 GraphicsRow[list, opts]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do:

```
showResults[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[ImageSize -> 444]] := 
     GraphicsRow[list, Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[GraphicsRow]]]

showResults[{1, 1}]
```

Comment: And yes, the Option (passing and filtering) mechanism in Mathematica is pretty inconvenient. There are rumors the whole language is being redesigned (because of the new Compiler). So let's hope things will improve then finally.

Comment: Thanks, Rolf. This is indeed a solution to my problem, but what is exactly wrong with my definition?

Comment: @OlegSoloviev The problem was that you submitted a _list_ of rules insead of a sequence of rules to `GraphicsRow`. Some built-in functions allow for that; others do not.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Nothing wrong with your solution. The implementation of GraphicsRow is buggy. You could submit the problem to support@wolfram.com.